# Invalid constant value. Flutter , google maps package

Tags: flutter, google-maps

```dart
onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
```

Invalid constant value.
how can i fix that ?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(36.71228369662267, 3.1805848553156153),
    zoom: 16.5,
  );

  GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _googleMapController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
        onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

1-went to the documentation and executed test code. same issue
2-google similar problems , but it didnt help
3- chat gpt and no help as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `const` before Scaffold( ...

Comment: omg , thank y so much , i'm new to flutter and i'm building my end of the year thesis and app and learning flutter at the same time , i totally forgot about the const on Scaffold , thank y again sir!